# Como Configurar variáveis de ambiente Maven/Java

Tags: java, maven

Configurei as seguintes variáveis de ambiente

```
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144%MAVEN%

MAVEN_HOME C:\Users\Rafael Storm\Desktop\apache-maven-3.5.2 - (extrai o Maven)

MAVEN %MAVEN_HOME%\bin

Path %JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

No entanto, quando tento checar o Maven...

```
C:\Users\Rafael Storm>mvn -version
'mvn' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.
```

Alguma dica ou variável que possa estar configurado errado?

Comment: Esta errado a config, retira do JAVA_HOME aquele %MAVEN%, cria uma M2_HOME e aponta para a pasta do maven depois no path usa Path %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin

Comment: Lembrando que como é windows qualquer config não vale para a janela de DOS atual, depois de configurado precisa fechar e abrir uma nova.

Answer (score 4):

Você não detalhou **exatamente** como fez, para entendermos onde pode ter sido o seu erro. Mas o [processo](https://mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/), no Windows, pode ser este abaixo.

Uma vez com o Maven baixado e descompactado em algum diretório:

1. Pressione a tecla do Windows no teclado e digite: "editar variáveis do sistema". **Clique** na opção que aparece.
2. Na tela de "Variáveis de Ambiente" que vai abrir, **clique** no botão "Novo" logo abaixo da parte da tela que diz "Variáveis de Sistema".
3. Nos campos nome e valor da variável, **preencha**: `MAVEN_HOME` e `C:\Users\Rafael Storm\Desktop\apache-maven-3.5.2`, respectivamente. Confirme.
4. Novamente nas "Variáveis de Sistema", **procure** pela variável `PATH` e **clique** em editar.
5. Na tela de "Editar variável de sistema", clique no botão "Novo" e adicione `%MAVEN_HOME%\bin`.
6. Confirme todas as telas até sair de todas elas.

Se tiver algum prompt de comando aberto, feche e abra ele novamente. O seguinte comando deve funcionar:

```
mvn -version
```

Answer (score 0):

Na variável **MAVEN_HOME** é necessário informar o caminho até a pasta BIN ou seja:
C:\Users\Rafael Storm\Desktop\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin
e se necessário adicione este caminho no Path também.

Answer (score -1):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema.

Utilizei o seguinte passo a passo

"editar variáveis do sistema" > "Variáveis de Ambiente" > "Novo" na parte "Variáveis de Sistema".
MAVEN_HOME e C:\Users\Rafael Storm\Desktop\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin
Edita a variável PATH adiciona o %MAVEN_HOME%\bin.

com isso já deve funcionar.

Só uma informação que o ideal seria vc deixar essa pasta no seu C ou no Arquivos de programas, no desktop não é recomendado...

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Para mim, não estava funcionando mesmo após configurar as Variáveis de Ambiente, porque a minha pasta do maven estava dentro da pasta "C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.4", então movi para pasta raiz "C\apache-maven-3.9.4" e funcionou. Vejo que você também coloquei a sua pasta do maven dentro da "Program Files", então talvez você tenha o mesmo problema que eu tive.

Answer (score -3):

Usei sua configuração:

JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144%MAVEN%
MAVEN_HOME C:\Users\Rafael Storm\Desktop\apache-maven-3.5.2 - (extrai o Maven)
MAVEN %MAVEN_HOME%\bin

Na variável do sistema adicionar o valor de "Path":

E adicionei o valor: "%caminho_maven%apache-maven-3.8.6\bin".

Obs.: Se ouver mais de uma variável adicionar um novo valor ou ';' antes.